# performing php script without reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript

```
<form action ="send.php" name ="userdetails" onsubmit="display(); return false;">
```

although this does perform the send.php script, it loads the send.php page and the content of the current page is lost.

I need to perform the following, once the form is submitted - an email should be sent. However the current page is not to be changed. What is the best way to accomplish this? Thank you

Comment: Ajax is the way to go.

Comment: can you give an example please

Comment: @Jon AJAX is the only way to go... :)

Comment: @cereallarceny how about iframe ??

Comment: One way would be to use a self action such as `<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">` and put your code based on conditions.

Comment: @Charlie Gah! Noooo! and @ cereallarceny, haha ^^

Comment: @Charlie `iframe`s are dead for this purpose. This isn't the 90's. :)

Comment: @cereallarceny What about WebSockets then? :P

Comment: @Paulpro How about saving them as cookies in javascript and then the next page load check for the cookies and send it based on that info? =P

Comment: I suppose you could do WebSockets, I don't know if this functionality needs something as deep as a socket server.  Not to mention the support for it wouldn't be that great.

Comment: @cereallarceny Haha, I'm only kidding about the WebSockets. Technically, in a modern browser, you could do it that way, but AJAX is the way to go lol.

Comment: Oh definitely, my point is that you could **only** do it in a modern browser. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a value for `action="..."` will always redirect you to a new page.

For what you want to do, AJAX is perfect. It allows you to run a PHP script without leaving the page you are on. I would check out [jQuery's AJAX capabilities](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: $.ajax(
        {
        method:'post',
        url:'send.php',
        data:
        {
            'username': user
        }
        })

Comment: that worked but it ignores url:'file.php', and this causes the script not to execute. I have mod rewrite rules in place but that shouldn't affect this because in the url i give the exact link to the php